# android application containing activities with different orientation

Tags: android

I have an activity group say mainActivity which contain 4 activity groups. say one, two, three and four.
All activities except fourth one has orientation portrait. The fourth activity group's orientation varies it may be portrait or landscape.

when i change fourth once orientation from portrait to landscape whole application restarts.

Is it possible to do such kind of things. that mainActivity group has orientation portrait and its child orientation is landscape. And also to allow to change child's orientation without restarting application.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent the activity from restarting by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity in AndroidManifest file. But it's generally not advisable to do that as stated in the documentation:

> Using this attribute should be avoided
>   and used only as a last-resort. Please
>   read Handling Runtime Changes for more
>   information about how to properly
>   handle a restart due to a
>   configuration change.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: we can set orientation in manifest so that application wont affect.